# MySQL why increasing limit from 20 to 21 reduces execution time from 1,4s to 0,0067s

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 230 000 rows
Query 1 duration 1,389 seconds

```
SELECT sql_no_cache `model_regulation_sections`.* 
FROM `model_regulation_sections` 
WHERE `model_regulation_sections`.`regulation_id` = 254 
ORDER BY `model_regulation_sections`.`lft` ASC 
LIMIT 20
```

Explain
select_type = SIMPLE 
table = model_regulation_sections
partitions = null`
type = index
possible_keys = document_id
key = lft
key_len = 4
ref = null
rows = 2229
filtered = 0.90
Extra = Using where

Query 2 duration 0,0067

```
SELECT sql_no_cache `model_regulation_sections`.* 
FROM `model_regulation_sections` 
WHERE `model_regulation_sections`.`regulation_id` = 254 
ORDER BY `model_regulation_sections`.`lft` ASC 
LIMIT 21
```

Explain
select_type = SIMPLE 
table = model_regulation_sections
partitions = null`
type = ref
possible_keys = document_id
key = lft
key_len = 4
ref = const
rows = 2251
filtered = 100
Extra = 'Using index condition; Using filesort'

MySQL why increasing limit from 20 to 21 reduces execution time from 1,4s to 0,0067s?

And why 2 hours ago the execution time of query 1 was 13,5 seconds?
I did not change the config.

Comment: Can you get some extra knowledge?

are you inside an sp?

How is the configuration of the server?

Comment: You do not appear to have an index on (regulation_id, lft) so the optimizer is doing the best that it thinks it can... but changing the data in the table changes the stats, and can skew the query plan, particularly when there's not a truly optimal plan available.  Can you try adding that index?

Comment: @victorvictord MySQL 5.7.11 Homebrew default config.    
`# Default Homebrew MySQL server config<br>     
    [mysqld]<br>
    # Only allow connections from localhost<br>
    bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot adding that index reduces execution time.
And i'm not sure but durationof query 1 reduced from 13,5s to 1,4 s after execution  with `ORDER BY model_regulation_sections.regulation_id, model_regulation_sections.lft`

Comment: I guess you aren't indexing clollumns, right?

Comment: There was index lft on field lft and regulation_id on field regulation_id. Query plan shows that mysql uses index lft in both queries. I think that key in Extra='Using index condition'. But i don't know why mysql does not uses extra when limit is 20 or less